# Draw horizontal and vertical lines in uiviewcontroller's view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with some images. I need to draw some horizontal and vertical lines in between images. Actually its like a hierarchy view. Is adding subviews with background color the best way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 basic approaches:

1. Use QuartzCore and override drawRect: in a custom UIView subclass
2. Set the borderWidth and borderColor of the UIImageView layer property that contains each image
3. Create UIViews of height 1 for horizontal lines and width 1 for vertical lines, set the backgroundColor of the views and add them as subviews

3 is probably the easiest to implement, but not the most elegant, 1 is the most robust in terms of memory as you can also use drawInRect to draw your images into the same graphics context.  This collapses the view hierarchy into a single view.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using layers as answered above or simply since you want just lines,use `UIViews`

Just like this

```
for(i=0;i<numberOfLine*heightofImage;i+=heightOfImage) {
    UIView *horizontalLine=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, i, height, 1)];
    [self.view addSubView:horizontalLine];
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is the 3rd option of the answer above.  Useful to add the code though.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView *verticalLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(roundf(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2), 0.0, 1.0, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    verticalLine.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    verticalLine.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    [self.view addSubview:verticalLine];

    UIView *horizontalLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, roundf(self.view.bounds.size.height / 2), self.view.bounds.size.width, 1.0)];
    horizontalLine.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    horizontalLine.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [self.view addSubview:horizontalLine];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the 3rd option posted by Magic Bullet Dave and it is working great. Here's the code:

```
UIView *borderBottom = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 10, widthDesired, 1.0)];
borderBottom.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[myView addSubview:borderBottom];
```

If you want to make a vertical line you'd simply use a width of 1 and then the height desired.